# Django: Update object from view, with no model or template

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm currently working on a Django app that allows users to set synonyms for keywords. 
Its using the following model:

```
class UserSynonym(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Tenant)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

A ListView provides users with an overview, and each entry is followed by an 'edit'  button that links to a relevant
EditView that allows the user to change the 'value' parameter.

I now want to add a button that allows the user to quickly reset the object to its original meaning (Set the 'value'  to the value of 'key')
I want this to be a single button, without any forms or html templates. Just a button on the list that, when pressed, 'resets'  the value of the model.

I reckon I have to edit an EditView for this task, however, these views keep demaning that I supply them with either a form or a HTML template/page
Which is not what I want to do.

Is there a way to change the EditView so that it changes the value of the object, without redirecting the user to a form or a new webpage?

EDIT: 
for completeness sake I've added the UpdateView as I'm currently using it

```
class SynonymUpdate(UserRootedMixin, UpdateView):
    model = UserSynonym
    form_class = SynonymCreateForm

  def get_form_kwargs(self):
      kwargs = super(SynonymUpdate, self).get_form_kwargs()
      kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
      return kwargs

  def form_valid(self, form):
      form.instance.linked_user = self.kwargs.get('user')
      return super(SynonymUpdate, self).form_valid(form)

  def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
      return reverse('synonym_list', args=[self.request.user.id])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sort of solved my problem. I gave up on using a class based view and used the following function instead:

```
def SynonymReset(request, user_id, pk):
  """(re)sets the Synonym.value to the value of Synonym.key"""

  #Get relevant variables
  currentuser = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
  currentsynonym = Synonym.objects.get(id = pk)

  #(re)set object & save
  currentsynonym.value = currentsynonym.key
  currentsynonym.save()

  #Return to the listview.
  return redirect('synonym_list', user=current_user)
```

This way the value is reset, without going to a seperate webpage. I still hope to one day find out how to do this in a class based view. But for now this will suffice.

Comment: There's absolutely no point querying the user here. `currentuser` is *exactly* the same db object as `request.user`; you should just pass that.